# What caused the switch?

Tags: savvy

In *Switch*, one of the sequels to *Savvy* by Ingrid Law, the savvies of several people—Gypsy, Samson, and their mother—"switched" to a different type. For instance, Gypsy froze the present instead of seeing the past and future; Samson glowed menacingly rather than becoming invisible and giving people strength.

This wasn't a global phenomenon, though: the savvies of other family members stayed the same. And its hard to tell what happened with Tucker, because Gypsy's vision suggested that he would get both his reversed power and his regular power, but perhaps it's a clue.

Now, it seems possible to me that the *why* isn't very important. The story's more about their emotional reaction. The book doesn't have an obvious answer, besides some speculation about Pat. So is she responsible? Is it something else? Does it have any tie to their emotional feelings (Samson seemed discontent with being invisible, Gypsy didn't like having visions she couldn't change, and their mother didn't like having to be perfect all the time).

What caused their savvies to switch?